# Number of times a certain value appear in a hastable

Tags: java, hashtable

My problem is, that i have a hash table which has about 1000000 entries and i need to find how many times a certain value appears in the hash table.

```
key1-->val1
key2-->val2
key3-->val3
key4-->val1
key5-->val1

output:
val1==3
val2==1
val3==1
```

Can I store same value under different keys?And if possible how can I find the number of appearances efficiently?

Comment: By the way, `Hashtable` itself in Java is obsolete. Use other key/value pair mechanisms like `Map`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can store the same value under different keys. To count the occurrences, I would perhaps maintain a secondary map that maps the value to a count. Every time you insert a value into the first map, you check to see if it has an entry in the second map. If it does, you can simply increment the count. Otherwise, you insert a new entry with a count of `1`.

Comment: What if I need to find it without doing such increment at the beginning?

Comment: Then you can't do it efficietly.

Comment: @Nadeeshaan Then you will have to build the map once and then maintain it after that. The initial cost will be expensive, but subsequent changes will not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a hashtable can store the same value under different keys. In Java, you can call the [Hashtable#values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#values%28%29) method to get all the values within that hashtable. You can then use it to count how many times a certain value occurs.

Given the big size of the hashtable (1 million entries), I would search for a more efficient solution (like the one proposed by [@Vivin Paliath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19985073/995822)).